# Preventing formaldehyde release from particleboards

Tags: safety, particle-board

I have a few particleboards that I want to use as cabinet boards. **What is the most simple way to reduce the release of formaldehyde?** Quick and cheap would be great.

Would it be sufficient to foil-coat them? If yes, would any kind of foil work or does it have to meet special requirements?

I don’t care how the boards will look/feel.

Comment: Do you know anything about the identity of the boards?  How old are they?

Comment: @fixer1234: The label says "P2-E1" and "raw". They were bought this year, but I don’t know how long the shop had them.

Comment: isn't E1 already really low in formaldehyde? (<1ppm) i would leave the boards in the windy sun for week if i were concerned, but on certified lumber like described it's unnecessary.

Comment: @dandavis: From what I read, anything worse than E1 is not approved for the interior of the house (in Germany), but multiple sources consider even E1 to be risky, especially if using multiple boards in a room. And the conditions under which E1 gets certified are said to be not realistic enough (for the test, they seem to seal the sawing edges; the temperature and humidity doesn’t vary like under real conditions etc.).

Comment: are you in the US? _In the United States, a bill was passed in Congress on July 7, 2010, regarding the use of formaldehyde in hardwood plywood, particle board, and medium density fiberboard. The bill limited the allowable amount of formaldehyde emissions from these wood products to .09 ppm, a standard which companies were required to meet by January 2013._

Comment: @dandavis: Germany (where it’s no more than 0.1 ppm for E1).